Problem with Tikz Picture and Latex Export from Org File
When trying to generate a tikzpicture as a figure for export the compilation fails with an error message about a missing aux file. However, I can see that the pdf is generated as a temporary file in the compiling directory and that the file named in *Org PDF LaTeX Output* is in fact present. Any suggestions.
Here is a minimal example that fails.
#+options: ':nil *:t -:t ::t <:t H:3 \n:nil ^:t arch:headline
#+title: New title
#+author: Britt Anderson
#+latex_class: article


* 
Introductory Material -- needs renaming.
** 
This is some text

#+header: :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}" "\\usepackage{string-diagrams}" "\\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}")
#+begin_src latex :results raw :file /home/britt/Desktop/string_test.pdf
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[box=0/1/1/0,
    text=black,align=center] (A) at (0,0) {Perceptual \\ Mechanism};
  \node[box=0/1/0/1,
    text=black,align=center] (B) at ($(A)+(4,0)$) {Central \\ Planning \\ System};
  \node[box=0/1/1/0,
    align=center] at (8,0) (C)  {Motor \\ System};
  \wires{
    A = {east = B.west, south = C.south},
    B = {east = C.west},
  }{}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
#+end_src

Addendum (by request)
Error message:
org-compile-file: File "/tmp/babel-4hbOcO/latex-mfAJfW.pdf" wasn’t produced.  See "*Org PDF LaTeX Output*" for details

Org PDF LaTeX Output details:
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(../../../tmp/babel-4hbOcO/latex-mfAJfW.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/capt-of/capt-of.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.te
x)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/string-diagrams/string-diagrams.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
calc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
positioning.code.tex) (./latex-mfAJfW.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1] (./latex-mfAJfW.aux) )
Output written on latex-mfAJfW.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on latex-mfAJfW.synctex.
Transcript written on latex-mfAJfW.log.
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(../../../tmp/babel-4hbOcO/latex-mfAJfW.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/capt-of/capt-of.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.te
x)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/string-diagrams/string-diagrams.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
calc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
positioning.code.tex) (./latex-mfAJfW.aux)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1] (./latex-mfAJfW.aux) )
Output written on latex-mfAJfW.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on latex-mfAJfW.log.
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'latex-mfAJfW.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'latex-mfAJfW.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(../../../tmp/babel-4hbOcO/latex-mfAJfW.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty

Package inputenc Warning: inputenc package ignored with utf8 based engines.

) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/t1lmr.fd))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/capt-of/capt-of.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.te
x)) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-xetex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvipdfmx.def
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex
) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex)

(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.t
ex) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex)
 (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.te
x) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
topaths.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/string-diagrams/string-diagrams.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
calc.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrary
positioning.code.tex)
No file latex-mfAJfW.aux.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd) [1] (./latex-mfAJfW.aux) )
Output written on latex-mfAJfW.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on latex-mfAJfW.log.

Values in init.el
;; (setq org-latex-compiler "pdflatex")
;; (setq org-latex-pdf-process '("pdflatex %f" "biber %b" "pdflatex %f" "pdflatex --synctex=-1 %f"))
(setq org-latex-compiler "xelatex")
(setq org-latex-pdf-process '("xelatex %f" "biber %b" "xelatex %f" "xelatex --synctex=-1 %f"))


Please post the error message(s) and the contents of *Org PDF LaTeX Output*.  FWIW, this works for me (after changing the :file path to something that exists on my system).

Question edited to include requested info.

One more request: can you add the value of org-latex-pdf-process to your question? Thanks!

Tried both the commented lines with pdflatex and the xelatex ones. Have not tried lualatex.

Thanks! I'll try things out and let you know.

You need to supply --output-directory=%o options on every command in your org-latex-pdf-process:
(setq org-latex-pdf-process '("xelatex --shell-escape --output-directory=%o %f" "biber --output-directory=%o %b" "xelatex --shell-escape  --output-directory=%o %f" "xelatex --shell-escape --output-directory=%o --synctex=-1 %f"))

I need --shell-escape on xelatex because I use minted but you probably don't need that.
Explanation to follow, but please try that and report back.

Yes. That does it.
